# Encoder class (org.owasp.esapi.reference.DefaultEncoder) CTOR threw exception

Tags: maven, encoding, esapi, xml-encoding

I am trying to run a sample program which encodes using ESAPI.

Here is the sample program

```
package hello;

import java.io.UnsupportedEncodingException;
import org.owasp.esapi.ESAPI;
import org.owasp.esapi.Encoder;
import org.owasp.esapi.errors.EncodingException;

public class Sample {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        
        
        String encodedString = encodeForXML("comma underscore hyphen");
        System.out.println("The encoded string is "+encodedString); 
        

    }
    

    
    public static String encodeForXML(String str)
    {
        return ESAPI.encoder().encodeForXML(str);
    }
    
    
    

}
```

This results in the exception

```
Exception in thread "main" org.owasp.esapi.errors.ConfigurationException: java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException Encoder class (org.owasp.esapi.reference.DefaultEncoder) CTOR threw exception.
    at org.owasp.esapi.util.ObjFactory.make(ObjFactory.java:129)
    at org.owasp.esapi.ESAPI.encoder(ESAPI.java:101)
    at hello.HelloWorld.encodeForXML(HelloWorld.java:24)
    at hello.HelloWorld.main(HelloWorld.java:14)
Caused by: java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:64)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:564)
    at org.owasp.esapi.util.ObjFactory.make(ObjFactory.java:86)
    ... 3 more
Caused by: java.lang.ExceptionInInitializerError
    at java.base/java.lang.Class.forName0(Native Method)
    at java.base/java.lang.Class.forName(Class.java:377)
    at org.owasp.esapi.util.ObjFactory.loadClassByStringName(ObjFactory.java:158)
    at org.owasp.esapi.util.ObjFactory.make(ObjFactory.java:81)
    at org.owasp.esapi.ESAPI.logFactory(ESAPI.java:139)
    at org.owasp.esapi.ESAPI.getLogger(ESAPI.java:155)
    at org.owasp.esapi.reference.DefaultEncoder.<init>(DefaultEncoder.java:83)
    at org.owasp.esapi.reference.DefaultEncoder.getInstance(DefaultEncoder.java:67)
    ... 8 more
Caused by: org.owasp.esapi.errors.ConfigurationException: Unable to locate resource: esapi-java-logging.properties
    at org.owasp.esapi.logging.java.JavaLogFactory.readLoggerConfiguration(JavaLogFactory.java:95)
    at org.owasp.esapi.logging.java.JavaLogFactory.<clinit>(JavaLogFactory.java:81)
    ... 16 more
```

I am using Maven build and included ESAPI dependency in my pom.xml and also included esapi.properties and validation.properties(both downloaded from here: https://github.com/ESAPI/esapi-java-legacy/releases/tag/esapi-2.2.1.1) in src/main/resources and both are successfully loaded as per the the message in console. Please let me know what I am missing out here.

Comment: You’re running without having loaded resources into your class path.  Maven only does part of the work for you.  You’ll have to specify those class path locations either through a -cp argument on the command line or by explicitly loading them into the current class’s class path.

Answer (score 1):

@avgvstvs is absolutely correct. If you look at the Javadoc for JavaLogFactory, it states:
"This implementation requires that a file named 'esapi-java-logging.properties' exists on the classpath."

The rules for ESAPI finding this particular property file is not the same as locating ESAPI.properties. There's a reason for that, but it's complicated to explain because logger components need to be bootstrapped a bit differently than the other ESAPI components.

Comment: Thank you @avgvstvs and Kevin - I followed this doc(https://owasp.org/www-pdf-archive/JavaEE-ESAPI_2.0a_install.pdf) section 3.4 step 1 to add my esapi-2.2.1.1.jar and esapi-2.2.1.1-sources.jar to my classpath as external JARs in eclipse IDE. But, still the same issue persists after doing maven install and ran the java application. Can you let me know what is the possible issue here?

Comment: That reference is ancient. It should probably be removed. There are some more recent links at https://github.com/ESAPI/esapi-java-legacy/wiki that explain how to do this with Maven and Eclipse, but you you have specific questions how to use ESAPI, please subscribe & then post to the esapi-project-users Google group described in https://github.com/ESAPI/esapi-java-legacy/blob/develop/README.md